# Find 4 combinations of buckets among 1000's such that choosen 4 buckets SUM of Weights must be below 100

Tags: python, linear-programming

I have 1000's of Buckets  and corresponding Weights ,I need all combination of 4 buckets Which Satisfies following Constriants.

1. Summation of all 4  bucket weights must be less than 100.

Say for Example here If I randomly choosen 4 buckets :

```
  Bucket_Name                          Weight(Kg)
    Bucket_1                             20        
    Bucket_2                             12          
    Bucket_3                             15        
    Bucket_4                             35         1
```

Sum(Weights) = 20+12+15+35= 82kg

1.Here I can use Python Itertools.combinations() but we get trillons of combinations.It takes days to run.
2.Even I can use Solver but Iam not able to get all possible combinations satisfying Weight Constriant.I tried uing Google OR tools Pywraplp.But Solver is
only choosing few combinations satisfying Weight Constriant.

I got Stucked here .Please help me out .

1. I tried using Python Itertools.combinations()  but we get trillions of combination of buckets.
2. I even tried using Google OR tools Solvers but Iam getting only few combinations of 4 buckets. Actually Solver is not picking all possible combinations of buckets satisfying Weight Constriant.

CAN anyone help me out with any other alternatives??

Comment: Are there ways to take advantage of the distribution of weights?  Are there duplicates?  Are there buckets such that the bucket weight is > 3 times the minimum bucket weight (instant elimination)

Comment: If you had 2000 buckets, that's roughly 600B combinations, so you could brute-force it if needed, but what would you do if you had 100B combinations that were acceptable?

Comment: You should publish the or-tools code. CP-SAT should find all of them easily, although there could be a lot of combinations.

Answer (score -1):

This program finds four ***consecutive*** buckets with sum of values < 100

```
# Generating a list with 4000 random values
import random

lst = []

for i in range(4000):
  lst.append(random.randrange(1, 100))

# Finding four consecutive buckets with sum of values < 100

b1 = lst[1]
b2 = lst[1]
b3 = lst[1]
b4 = lst[1]

for i in range(len(lst)):
  if (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4) < 100:
    print(b1)
    print(b2)
    print(b3)
    print(b4)
    break;
  else:
    b1 = b2
    b2 = b3
    b3 = b4
    b4 = lst[i+5]
```